# Laravel Framework php

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I've made an online store in php for school, and now my teacher wants this project to have a Laravel Framework. And I have no freaking idea how to do it. Are there any possibilities to implement this framework to my project, or my project to this framework, without starting from scratch?  If yes, how should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

irrespective, its going to involve a lot of rework. A lot also comes to down to HOW you've developed your original php app. Laravel is a Model View Controller framework. For starters all your routes (http redirects) are generally managed in a single file (web.php). Your views can be traditional php, however, Laravel gives you a good templating engine called Blade which allows you to shorthand code and keep code a lot cleaner. Models control your table relationships, controllers handle the functions/code/crud etc.

You will love how easy it is in most respects - especially the way eloquent data queries work etc. It can greatly reduce your code.

If your teacher wants you to LEARN Laravel specifically, I would say YES you will be starting over - however, your logic in the code should just need reworking rather than start from scratch.

There are heaps of posts around HOW to install Laravel (apache, virtual box, homestead etc) - once your ready, its super simple to create a new project and start building away... If you are new to MVC, you should do some tutorials first (e.g. laracasts or other).

Best of luck :)